# Perform a three-way join

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have three entities which are related as follows:

- Castle: belongs to a Player
- Player: is a member of an alliance

These are my models:

```
def ReferenceCol(tablename, nullable=False, pk_name='id', **kwargs):
    """Column that adds primary key foreign key reference.

    Usage: ::

        category_id = ReferenceCol('category')
        category = relationship('Category', backref='categories')
    """
    return db.Column(
        db.ForeignKey("{0}.{1}".format(tablename, pk_name)),
        nullable=nullable, **kwargs)

class Player(Model):

    __tablename__ = 'players'
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    player_name = Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    alliance_id = ReferenceCol('alliances', nullable=True)
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Player({player_name!r})>'.format(player_name=self.player_name)


class Alliance(Model):

    __tablename__ = 'alliances'
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    alliance_name = Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Alliance({alliance_name!r})>'.format(alliance_name=self.alliance_name)


class Habitat(Model):

    __tablename__ = 'habitats'
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    castle_name = Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=True)
    player_id = ReferenceCol('players', nullable=True)
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Habitat({castle_name!r})>'.format(castle_name=self.castle_name)
```

I can easily join habiats and players:

```
# Join habitats and players
for habitat, player in db.session.query(Habitat, Player).join(Player).all()[:3]:
    print habitat, player
```

And players and alliances:

```
# Join players and alliances
for player, alliance in db.session.query(Player, Alliance).join(Alliance).all()[:3]:
    print player, alliance
```

But how to join all three tables? How can I join habitats, players and alliances? I am looking for something to do:

```
for castle, player, alliance in magic_join():
    print castle, player, alliance
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass multiple models to [join](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join).  Order matters: if you query for `Habitat`, you'll only get players with habitats and alliances with players.  If you query for `Alliance` with outer joins, you'll get all the alliances, with their players and their habitats.

```
for a, p, h in session.query(Alliance, Player, Habitat).outerjoin(Player, Habitat):
    print(a.id, p.id, h.id)
```

---

Rather than querying multiple objects, define [relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship).  Query for `Alliance` and use [eager loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#eager-loading) to load the relationships without extra queries.  Iterate over the alliances, and for each alliance iterate over its players, etc.

```
class Alliance(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'alliance'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    alliance_id = sa.Column(sa.ForeignKey(Alliance.id), nullable=False)
    alliance = orm.relationship(Alliance, backref='players')

class Habitat(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'habitat'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    player_id = sa.Column(sa.ForeignKey(Player.id), nullable=False)
    player = orm.relationship(Player, backref='habitats')
```

```
for a in session.query(Alliance).options(
    db.joinedload(Alliance.players).joinedload(Player.habitats)
):
    for p in a.players:
        for h in p.habitats:
            print(a.id, p.id, h.id)
```